# URL won't open swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl

```
@IBAction func download(_ sender: Any) {
    if let url = URL(string: "\(imgURL)") {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    }
    print(imgURL)
}
```

The url wont open if i press the button. The consol says the right url: https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/18514045_212505245924563_1350282415863496704_a.jpg but the url wont open. Please help! Thanks

```
                   let urlstr = "\(profile_pic_url_hd)"
                        if var comps = URLComponents(string: urlstr) {
                            var path = comps.path
                            var pathComps = path.components(separatedBy: "/")
                            pathComps.remove(at: 2) // this removes the s320x320
                            path = pathComps.joined(separator: "/")
                            comps.path = path
                            if let newStr = comps.string {
                                print(newStr)
                                self.imgURL = "\(newStr)"
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL`? Just use `URL` in Swift.

Comment: And what is `imgURL`? Is it a String, a URL, an NSURL?

Comment: I have changed it to `URL` but is still doesnt work

Comment: imgURL is a string

Comment: Then simply use `if let url = URL(string: imgURL) {`. Don't needlessly use string interpolation.

Comment: it worked! Thanks!

Comment: You have a few other inappropriate uses of string interpolation in the code you posted. You should get rid of them too.

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me